# How to resolve 'Invalid project directory provided, no such directory: /vercel/path0/run?' error on Vercel when deploying a website?

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, vercel

I have successfully made changes to a page in my app, pushed it to Git without any issues. However, when attempting to deploy the website on the Vercel platform, I encountered the following error:

> Invalid project directory provided, no such directory: /vercel/path0/run?

How can I resolve this issue and successfully deploy my website on Vercel? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
  output: 'export',
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1000,
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    PROJECT_ROOT: __dirname,
  },
  images: {
    domains: [
      'res.cloudinary.com',
      'avatars.githubusercontent.com',
      'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
      'www.instagram.com',
    ],
  },
}
```

This is the error I am facing on Vercel

[image: Error Vercel deployment Dashboard]